# Performing operations in text file using T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, file, t-sql, sql-server-2016

I have a text file in which need to perform operation like file has headers at all, if have headers then it pass to next if not then operations should stop.
Second step to find have proper delimiter i.e pipe if file have proper delimiter then it should pass and move next step, otherwise fail.
If all the above steps is success then it should get exported to main table.

File structure is :

```
A|B|C|D|E - column
00|1|1|1|1- data
.
```

.
So on.

```
create table #testdata (
textvalue varchar(max)
)


bulk insert #testdata
from 'D:\test.txt'
--with 
--(
--FIELDTERMINATOR = '|'
--)

select  *,rowid = row_number() over(order by textvalue desc) 
into    #test1
from    #testdata


--if exists (select 1 from #test1 where #test1.textvalue = @header and #test1.rowid = 1)
--begin
goto nextstep
--end
else
goto exitprocedure
```

Output should be like this : -

```
select FileType = 'Test',
       ReviewType = 'Correct delimiter is expected',
       PassFail = 'Success or Fail'
```

based on the above validation whichever is failed it should show output as above three filed.

Since this need to perform in T-SQL.

Comment: SO is about assisting you to build a solution, not doing it all for you. Please have a go and post a specific question when you get stuck.

Comment: @DaleK i am using bulk operation and storing them in temp table and performing the operation but not getting exactly how we will verify header of a file and delimiter of every column is correct or not.

Comment: You need to [edit] that sort of detail into the question.

Comment: SO is not a free coding service website!!!  You are expected to try to solve your problem.  If it doesn't work, we will try to help.

Comment: Also, read this to learn how to ask question.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @Eric i tried myself and after i get stuck and i have little less knowledge about tsql . I edited and posted how i have been trying. I know i am not correct  but hoping get help from you guys.

Comment: Sounds like it is better to do this outside of `SQL Server`. Any particular reason you wanted to do this in `SQL Server` ?

Comment: You might want to look into SSIS (SQL Server Integration Services) or some other ETL (Extract Transform & Load) technology. This kind of problem is exactly what it (they) were created for.

Comment: You haven't actually explained your issue. Descriptions like "not getting", "no correct" don't mean anything. I suggest you post the output of your file and explain what the issue is with it.

Comment: I have to disagree that SSIS was built for this. If the file doesn't have a fixed format or it's dirty in any way you have to resort to C# script etc. SSIS doesn't play well with inconsistent input data formats.

Comment: Please state your SQL-Server's version

Comment: @Shnugo SQL server version is 2016.

Comment: @Squirrel actually we dependent on T-SQL only because we have some other validation also post we export to main table and in one go we to want validate all the logic. Any idea how we can achieve will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

As you were told already T-SQL is not the right tool for this...

The string manipulation abilities are rather weak, but you might try along one of these routes:

I start to simulate with a variable containing your text file's content.

```
DECLARE @YourFile VARCHAR(MAX)=
'A|B|C|D|E
01|1|1|1|1
02|2|2|2|2';
```

--declare variables for the line break and the delimiter

```
DECLARE @YourLineBreak VARCHAR(2)=CHAR(13)+CHAR(10); --might differ...
DECLARE @YourDelimiter VARCHAR(1)='|';
```

--This query will transform your file into XML

```
DECLARE @YourInput XML=
CAST(CONCAT('<line><val>'
    ,REPLACE(REPLACE(@YourFile,@YourDelimiter,'</val><val>'),@YourLineBreak,'</val></line><line><val>')
    ,'</val></line>') AS XML);

SELECT @YourInput;
```

--This query will return the column names

```
SELECT A.cols.value('text()[1]','varchar(max)') AS ColumnName
FROM @YourInput.nodes('/line[1]/*') A(cols) ;
```

--This query will return each data row as a single line

```
WITH CountRows(LineIndex) AS(SELECT TOP((SELECT @YourInput.value('count(/line)','int')-1)) ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) FROM master..spt_values)
SELECT LineIndex
      ,@YourInput.query('/line[sql:column("LineIndex")+1]') AS LineValues
FROM CountRows;
```

--In this query I first *inject* a numbers sequence, which can be used in XQuery later

```
WITH InjectSequence(Combined) AS
(
    SELECT (SELECT TOP((SELECT @YourInput.value('count(/line[1]/val)','int'))) ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) FROM master..spt_values FOR XML PATH('Nmbr'),TYPE)
          ,@YourInput
    FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE
)
SELECT Combined.query
('
    let $cols := /line[1]/val
    for $ln in /line[position()>1]
    return
    <line>
    {
        for $nr in /Nmbr/text() 
        let $n := xs:int($nr)
        return
        <val name="{$cols[$n]}" value="{$ln/val[$n]}" />
    }
    </line>
')
FROM InjectSequence;
```

What ever approach you choose, you will have to do quite a lot if manual work.

The final query will have to be either dynamically created or you can stay within generic containers such as XML or JSON.

### With SQL-Server 2016 there is JSON

With v2016+ you mgiht try the JSON route too:

```
SELECT B.*
FROM OPENJSON(CONCAT('[',STUFF(CONCAT(',[["',REPLACE(REPLACE(@YourFile,@YourDelimiter,'","'),@YourLineBreak,'"],["'),'"]]'),1,1,''),']')) A
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(A.[value])
WITH(col1 VARCHAR(MAX) '$[0]'
    ,col2 VARCHAR(MAX) '$[1]'
    ,col3 VARCHAR(MAX) '$[2]'
    ,col4 VARCHAR(MAX) '$[3]'
    ,col5 VARCHAR(MAX) '$[4]') B --add as many as you need
```

Good luck!